# Show there exists an $f$ s.t. $f(x)>0$ for $x \in C$ where $C$ is compact

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, compactness

I thought to use the same functions $h$ as we used in (c) but the problem is the $h$ is positive on $(a^1-\epsilon,a^1+\epsilon) \times ... \times (a^n - \epsilon, a^n + \epsilon)$ which is not compact. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is compact if [each open cover has a finite subcover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Open_cover_definition), i.e. from
$$
    C  \subset \bigcup_{a \in C}(a^1-\epsilon,a^1+\epsilon) \times \cdots \times (a^n - \epsilon, a^n + \epsilon) 
$$
it follows that there is a *finite* set $S \subset C$ such that
$$
    C  \subset \bigcup_{a \in S}(a^1-\epsilon,a^1+\epsilon) \times \cdots \times (a^n - \epsilon, a^n + \epsilon) 
$$
For each $a \in S$, define $h_a$ as the function defined in (c)
for the "cube" $(a^1-\epsilon,a^1+\epsilon) \times \cdots \times (a^n - \epsilon, a^n + \epsilon)$.

Then $f := \sum_{a \in S} h_a$ has the desired properties.